# Same ID with different value inserted into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to insert same id with different value into database. Basically it is a form which allow the user to add new scholarship with some criteria. Not all scholarships will be applicable to all courses. Hence there will be two tables, `scholarship` which will take the new scholarships, and `scholarshipCourse` which will handle the eligibility of courses.

I want to insert both data at the same time. where the user press submit, the scholarship id in `scholarship` table will be auto increment whereas the `scholarshipcourse` table will take the new scholarship id and insert

For example:

Table `scholashipCourse`:

```
scholarship_id    course
-------------------------
    1             math
    1             english
    2             english
    2             science
```

Table `scholarship`:

```
scholarship_id     scholarshipName 
--------------------------------------
      1            moon scholarship
      2            star scholarship
      3            light scholarship
```

Assume scholarship_id 3 is the new added scholarship, how do i get that id and insert into the scholarshipcourse table simultaneously.

I can use this select statement:

```
INSERT INTO user (name) 
VALUES ('John Smith');

INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height)
VALUES (SELECT(id FROM user WHERE name = 'John Smith'), 83, 185);
```

but how do I get the latest id that has just be added?

i will need to insert to my DAL like:

public DataTable test(string name, string course)
        {

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(schName)  values (@schName)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schName", name);
        conn.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        cmd.CommandText = "Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();INSERT INTO Table2(ScholarshipID,DiplomaCourse) values (@id,@course)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;

    }
```

it is successfully added to two tables but it does not retrieve the last id and insert to the table

Comment: You don't -- you can't do it simultaneously -- insert it in the scholarship table and get the id and then insert it in the course table.

Comment: so after inserting the new added scholarship then i retrieve the id and insert into course table?

Answer (score 1):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a possible solution.

**Description of SCOPE_IDENTITY:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Basically you insert into the scholarship table and get the id (with SCOPE_IDENTITY). Then, using that id, you insert into the scholarshipCourse table. Something like this (based on your scholarship table names):

```
DECLARE @id INT
INSERT INTO scholarshipCourse (course) VALUES ('humanities')
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() --RETRIEVES THE LAST INSERTED ID IN THIS SCOPE
INSERT INTO scholarship (scholarship_id, scholarshipName) VALUES (@id, 'star scholarship')
```

Comment: i have nvr try using scope_identity before. it is something new to me. is there any other way?

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY is fairly standard and recommended. @@IDENTITY is also a possibility, but SCOPE_IDENTITY is recommended.

Comment: I see you have updated the question. I added some possible sample code to my answer.

Comment: i think i want it the other way round. so i think i should insert scholarship first and then get the id of that scholarship and insert into scholarshipcourse. does that code work or i need to rearrange the code?

Comment: i have tested out using sql query and its successfully inserted into db exactly the way i want. but i have yet to try to test in my DAL and see if it works or not. Anyways, thanks for the help. i will come back if i have error execute it in the proper way

Comment: Hi how do i write those statement in class file?

Comment: That's a very broad question. You mentioned your DAL. What kind of Data Access Layer are you using? That will determine how you implement this in a C# class file.

Comment: i have just edited my question again on how i have use my DAL. i cant displayed it here because it does not allow me to use @MattSpinks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to capture the values of the newly-inserted record, including identity values:

```
INSERT INTO user (name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES ('John Smith');
```

The `INSERT` statement will produce a result set which contains the ID of each inserted record (in the above case, a single row).  You can execute the command as you would a query (e.g., if inserting a single row, using `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace you inline select statement with scope_identity function.

```
INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('John Smith');
INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height) VALUES (scope_identity(), 83, 185);
```

and if you want to insert more than one detail row
you can declare a variable and set it's value to scope_identity

```
INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('John Smith');
declare @id int
select @id=scope_identity()
INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('John Smith');
INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height) VALUES (@id, 83, 185);
INSERT INTO user_details (id, weight, height) VALUES (@id, 84, 186);
```

Comment: Why is user table here?  User table and user details have nothing to do with this question -- looks like you copied an answer from a different question and didn't even edit it.

Comment: Read at the full question first please and look at the example he placed at the bottom!!